# What could be the opposite of a 'Topicalized language'?

Tags: syntax

There're languages with topicalization system like Philippines, English, etc. I was wondering since the counterpart of 'Ergative' is 'Accusative', what could be the counterpart of a 'topicalized language'?

Comment: English is not actually a [topic-prominent language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topic-prominent_language). I'm not sure how common this term is, but Wikipedia contrasts it with subject prominent.

Comment: Just in case the text changes in the future, Wikipedia's nomenclature of "topic prominent" vs. "subject prominent" follows Li and Thompson's *Subject and Topic: A New Typology of Language* (1976).

Comment: “Topic-prominence” is a scale so there’s no direct opposite. All languages are more or less sensitive to topic-focus articulation.